# Script to open terminal and show the output of the running commands

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I preface this by saying I am pretty much a complete noob when it comes to script writing.

Anyway, I am looking to create a script that opens a terminal in the GUI environment of Ubuntu, and when it does, shows the output of the other commands running in the script.

The reason for this is I am looking to take the script, throw it into the directory that runs scripts on log in and have it opening a terminal, run my normal update scripts and then keep the terminal open to allow me to continue after.

My reason is basically to just get more experience, and I figured to automate something I do every time I login.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want to do: if the goal is to run a single script, you can use a single command to bump up `gnome-terminal` and execute the script for you, there's no need to put `gnome-terminal` inside the script itself as it adds unnecessary complexity; do you want to run a single script or multiple scripts? Nonetheless is your goal to run it / them at startup or do you want to create a script that triggers the execution of the script / multiple scripts when explicitly executed?

Comment: I want to run 1 script. Basically I want on login to have terminal automatically open, and then have apt-get update/upgrade/dist-upgrade run, showing the output in that screen. That's all.

Comment: Ok, I've undeleted and updated my previously deleted answer, it should do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to run 1 script. Basically I want on login to have terminal automatically open, and then have apt-get update/upgrade/dist-upgrade run, showing the output in that screen. That's all.

Make sure your script is executable and add this command to Startup Applications:

```
gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade; exec bash"'
```

This will open `gnome-terminal`, which will start a non-interactive `bash` shell (which will run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`) and will later replace the current shell with an interactive `bash` shell.

If you have `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` already in a script, it would probably be more pratical to set Startup Applications to launch the script and maintain the script instead of the command in Startup Applications:

```
gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c "/path/to/script.sh; exec bash"'
```

Answer (score 0):

This command also works perfectly :

```
xfce4-terminal -x /usr/bin/expect -c 'spawn /usr/bin/bash ; expect "$ " ; send "update" ; interact ; exit'
```

You need to check if expect is in the bin path. Otherwise install the package.